# How do you determine whether a graph G has a spanning tree of weight k?

Tags: algorithm, tree

given k, a positive integer, and a connected graph G=(V, E), each e of E has a weight w(e), can anyone come up with an algo to determine if G has a spanning tree of weight k?

Comment: Exactly k I assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is NP-hard. We can show this by reduction from the following formulation of [the *subset sum* problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem):

> Given the […] natural numbers *w*<sub>1</sub>, …, *w*<sub>*n*</sub>, does any subset of them sum to precisely *W*?

To wit, suppose that we have an algorithm for solving your problem. We can then solve the subset sum problem (in the formulation above) by creating a graph *G* consisting of the following:

- vertices *v*<sub>1</sub>, …, *v*<sub>*n*</sub> corresponding to the elements of the set, plus two special vertices *x* and *y*.
- an edge from *x* to each *v*<sub>*i*</sub>, with weight *w*<sub>*i*</sub>.
- an edge from *y* to each *v*<sub>*i*</sub>, with weight 0.
- an edge from *x* to *y*, with weight 0.

The original set has a subset with sum *W* if and only if your algorithm returns "yes" for graph *G* and *k* = *W*.

To see why:

- If your algorithm returns "yes", then there is a spanning tree with weight *W*, meaning that the edges in the spanning tree add up to *W*. But the nonzero edge-weights are all distinct elements in the set, so this means we have a subset that sums to *W*.
- Conversely, if there is a subset that sums to *W*, then we can construct a spanning tree with weight *W* by taking the edges from *x* to the vertices corresponding to that subset, plus the (zero-weight) edges from *y* to all other vertices, plus the (zero-weight) edge from *x* to *y*.

---

Of course, NP-hardness doesn't mean you can't do it. It just means that there's no known algorithm that's correct *and efficient* for all possible inputs.

One *inefficient* algorithm is to generate all possible spanning trees, and see if any of them have the correct weight.

You can also check some likely cases more efficiently; in particular, you can use [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to find the minimal spanning tree, and (with slight modification) to find the maximal spanning tree. This will let you quickly eliminate any *k* outside the range of possible spanning tree weights.

Another possible way to eliminate many values of *k* is to use some of the algorithms for subset sum problems (at the Wikipedia article I linked to above) in order to determine whether the graph has *any* subgraph with weight *k*.

Comment: This is true, yet even if P ≠ NP it doesn't rule out an algorithm whose running time is polynomial in k and the size of the graph. I wonder if the spanning tree constraint makes this problem strongly NP-hard.